# The page isn’t working. Error 500

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting an error on my page:

```
The lunatixcr.com page isn’t working

lunatixcr.com is currently unable to handle this request.

HTTP ERROR 500
```

I am setting Wordpress from zero, I have set up the database and I have never logged in into the admin panel, actually I can't because basically I can't do anything due to the error I showed you above.

This is how my scaffold looks on filezilla

[image]

And the error:

[image]

Suggestions?

Comment: Check your error logs for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: What is in the .htaccess file - usually this isn't present until you've done the install. Have you added the database details to the wp-config.php?

Answer (score 3):

I am currently seeing the following:

```
Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.
```

That indicates that PHP needs to have mysql enabled for you to continue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use another browser to test? I know if you use Safari and put error reporting on, you can see the PHP-errors in your browser